# Do I have this written properly? .equals AND !.equals if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

FIXED. To get the statement to evaluate the way I wanted it to I had to write it this way:

```
public static Boolean pushCard(String S1, String S2) {
    Boolean result = false; 

    if ((S1.equals("fire")  || S1.equals("wind") || S1.equals("water")))
        if (!S2.equals("fire") && (!S2.equals("water") && (!S2.equals("fire"))))
            result = true;

    return result;
} //end push card method
```

I can not tell if this comparison is causing issues. I was using == instead of .equals but then I learned that it was the wrong way to write it. Thanks for the help!

```
public static Boolean pushCard(String S1, String S2) {
    Boolean result = false; 

    if ((S1.equals("fire")  || S1.equals("wind") || S1.equals("water")))
        if (!S2.equals("fire") || (!S2.equals("water") || (!S2.equals("fire"))))
            result = true;

    return result;
} //end push card method
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: Yes, you have it right.

Comment: All sorts of odd craziness, too much to explain....

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744953/string-comparison-with-logical-operator-in-java regarding using == or equals for String comparisons if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: I just realised that I have the top statement encapsulated differently than the bottom. Is one right and the other not? I am very new BTW. I know that .equals is the best for comparing strings and == is best for comparing objects.

Comment: ^ no. `.equals` is what you should use for objects. `==` is for comparing primitives (ints, booleans, etc)

Comment: You are checking `!S2.equals("fire")` two times in your second if. Also `!S2.equals("fire") || (!S2.equals("water")` will always be true. If `S2` is not fire then `!S2.equals("fire")` will be `true`, if it is fire then `!S2.equals("water")` will be `true`.

Comment: == will compare references, which is usually not what you want. .equals will compare contents, which is usually what you want.

Comment: @Nerves82 Check out my answer.  Not sure if your code is going to give you what you want (I highlighted a potential logical issue).

Comment: Basicly I want the S1 string to be "fire" "wind" or "water" and S2 to be empty for the statement to return true. I am testing the crap out of this statement and I cannot get the second iff to evaluate properly. No matter what is held by S2, it returns "true". I think Pshemo hit on the problem but I don't understand what the proper syntax would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntactically, your code will compile just fine, and the way you use `.equals()` method to compare strings is correct.  Your use of the `!` operator is also correct.

There is no guarantee that your code will not have logical errors though.

Comment: Those where the item I needed answers too. Thanks!

Comment: Minor improvement: put the constant Strings on the left side, e.g. `"fire".equals(S1)`.  This allows for S1 or S2 to be null without throwing a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can see you have `"fire"` mentioned twice in your second `if` statement. Otherwise, any problems you might be having could be related to your logic being wrong, since your syntax is pretty much correct and your usage is proper.

Comment: Oh snap! It is always the simple things you don't see. Thanks for pointing that out. That would cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you're asking. The second `if` will always be `true`. You probably need :

```
if ((S1.equals("fire")  || S1.equals("wind") || S1.equals("water")))
    if (!S2.equals("fire") && (!S2.equals("water") && (!S2.equals("wind"))))
        result = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static Boolean pushCard(String S1, String S2)    
{
    Boolean result = false; 

    if (S1.equals("fire")  || S1.equals("wind") || S1.equals("water"))
        {
           (!S2.equals("fire") || !S2.equals("water"))
            result = true;
        }

    return result;

}
```

/end push card method

1. you had an extra pair of brackets in the first if statement.
2. I believe an if statement needs brackets {}  when the code inside it is larger than one line.
3. your second if statement can be altered to  just !S2.equals("fire") || !S2.equals("water")

Comment: Just from curiosity, why you decided to create new answer and delete old one if you could just edit old one?

Comment: lol I accidently posted. When I tried to edit it, it wouldn't let me see the question, so I just deleted the accident post and made a new one :/