# reading excel files through Java

Tags: java, excel, bufferedreader

I am trying to compare two files using BufferedReader but the == operator is not working, I am new to using the BufferedReader any thoughts on why it isn't working?

Comment: do you use excel files or csv? open file in notepad

Comment: If you're using CSV files, you could use `CSVReader`, a part of OpenCSV: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html

Comment: For xls files - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be that the java string == operator checks for more than if the text is the same, as described here:

[String comparison with logical operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744953/string-comparison-with-logical-operator-in-java)

what does it do if you use the string equals() method ?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)